# Neo4j: Connection with Power Bi

Tags: jdbc, import, neo4j, powerbi, connector

I saw that Neo4j developed a new connector for visual analytical programs, the connector is downloadable at the following link:

https://neo4j.com/bi-connector/?ref=pr-

Does this connector also work for Power Bi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve just found that the answer is NO, yet:

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/what-works-with-the-bi-connector/